# Area of ellipse formed by slicing a cylinder

Tags: area, geometry

What is the equation of the area of the ellipse when a cylinder of radius x is cut by a plane inclined at an angle a.

Angle a is the angle between the plane and the axis of the cylinder. If a is 90 then what we get is a circle of radius x.

PS. Consider the cylinder to be very long so that the plane cuts the cylinder completely

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some trigonometry to find the length of the major axis. A little thought should convince you that the length of the minor axis is $2x$. This is all the information you need to find the area.

Comment: (+1) Exactly. We get $A=\frac{\pi x^2}{\sin\alpha}$.